# Not able to record Application Login-sequence on Jmeter requiring [ADFS/SSO-authentication]

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, single-sign-on, record

1. 

Summary of the problem
Not able to record Application Login-sequence on Jmeter requiring [ADFS/SSO-authentication]
2. what we are trying
When trying with Jmeter-HTTPS_script recorder, its giving - message:
Your connection is not provate.
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Error with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this message because JMeter's certificate is [**self-signed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) hence it is not known by any [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)

This is kind of normal because JMeter generates certificate first time when you launch [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), the certificate is valid for 7 days (as of [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html)) and it's being regenerated after 7 days are passed.

Just ignore this message, click "Advanced" followed by "Proceed to xxxxx" (make sure that certificate is called `_ JMeter Root CA for recording (INSTALL ONLY IF IT S YOURS)`) and you should be good to go.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for picking up this thread. actually my application is a SSO-authenticated web-app with SAMLfeature that causes complete failure on chrome when tried with Jmeter-proxy.

the message is NET-ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Comment: 2-actually my application is a SSO-authenticated web-app with SAMLfeature that causes complete failure on chrome when tried with Jmeter-proxy.
the message is NET-ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Comment: 3-Under Advanced, there is no option to Proceed, because i am already  accepted the risk level.

Comment: 4-it says -
<Application-domain> normally uses encryption to protect your information.

Comment: 5-When Google Chrome tried o connect to <Application-domain> this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be <Application-domain>, or a Wi-FI sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged. 
You cannot visit <Application-domain> right now because the website uses HSTS Network errors and attacks are usuall temproary

Comment: Messages 1 - 6 didnt fit together once , so had to put in pieces. really sorry for this nonsesnse.